# Import defined selenium function browser issue

Tags: python, function, selenium, python-import

**Set-up**

I use selenium for a variety of things and found myself defining the same functions over and over again.

I decided to define the functions in a separate file, and import these to my work files.

---

**Simple Example**

If I define functions and execute all in one file, things work fine. See the simple **full_script.py** below,

```
# import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver

# create browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path='/mypath/geckodriver')

# define short xpath function
def el_xp(x):
    return browser.find_element_by_xpath(x)      

# navigate to url
browser.get('https://nos.nl')

# obtain title first article
el_xp('/html/body/main/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a/div[2]/h3').text
```

This successfully returns the title of the first article on this news website.

---

**Problem**

Now, when I split the script in a **xpath_function.py** and a **run_text.py**, and save them in a `test` folder on my desktop, things don't work fine.

**xpath_function.py**

```
# import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver

# create browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path='/mypath/geckodriver')

# define short xpath function
def el_xp(x):
    return browser.find_element_by_xpath(x)
```

**run_test.py**

```
import os
os.chdir('/my/Desktop/test')
import xpath_function as xf

# import webdriver
from selenium import webdriver

# create browser
browser = webdriver.Firefox(
        executable_path='/Users/lucaspanjaard/Documents/RentIndicator/geckodriver')

browser.get('https://nos.nl')

xf.el_xp('/html/body/main/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a/div[2]/h3').text
```

Executing `run_test.py` results in 2 browsers opened, of which one navigates to the news website and the following error,

```
NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: 
/html/body/main/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a/div[2]/h3
```

I suppose the issue is that in both `xpath_function.py` and `run_test.py` I'm defining a `browser`.

However, if I don't define a browser in `xpath_function.py`, I get an error in that file that no browser is defined.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily fix it by changing the definition of `el_exp` to include the browser as an extra parameter:

```
def el_xp(browser, x):
    return browser.find_element_by_xpath(x)
```

now in `run_test.py` you call it like this:

```
xf.el_xp(browser, '/html/body/main/section[1]/div/ul/li[1]/a/div[2]/h3').text
```